# Nonblocking fetching of data with Tornado websockets and RethinkDB

Tags: python, tornado, rethinkdb, rethinkdb-python

When I receive a message from a client I want to run multiple RethinkDB queries in parallel and send the results the client immediately.

The blocking way is below. A count can take minutes. I would like the other queries that would return faster to not be held up by the count query.

```
self.write_message({'count': r.db('public').table(message['table']).count().run(conn)})
self.write_message({'rows': r.db('public').table(message['table']).limit(10).run(conn)})
```

I suspect I need a combination of https://rethinkdb.com/blog/async-drivers/ and http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/guide/async.html

I'm thinking maybe the answer is to make those two lines something like:

```
ioloop.IOLoop.current().add_callback(run_query, r.db('public').table(message['table']).count(), 'count', self)
ioloop.IOLoop.current().add_callback(run_query, r.db('public').table(message['table']).limit(10), 'rows', self)
```

My run-query would be:

```
@gen.coroutine
def run_query(query, key, ws):
    conn = yield r.connect(host="localhost", port=28015)
    results = yield query.run(conn)
    ws.write_message({key: results})
```

Comment: Is there any reason why this needs to happen in tornado? This is exactly what node.js is very good at.

Comment: Only because I find the Python language more enjoyable to work with.

Comment: Agreed. But as much as I love python I've come to accept that javascript is almost always the best tool for the job when it comes to realtime web applications.

Comment: That being said, python might be [catching up soon](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html) and I'm hoping we'll start to see more python solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tornado.gen` [doc](http://tornadokevinlee.readthedocs.org/en/latest/gen.html) reveals solution:

> You can also yield a list or dict of Futures, which will be started at
>   the same time and run in parallel; a list or dict of results will be
>   returned when they are all finished.

```
# do not forget about this
r.set_loop_type("tornado")

@gen.coroutine
def run_parallel(query, key, ws):
    conn = yield r.connect(host="localhost", port=28015)
    ret = yield {
        'count': r.db('public').table(message['table']).count().run(conn),
        'rows': r.db('public').table(message['table']).limit(10).run(conn)
    }
    ws.write_message(ret)
```

Yielding list or dict directly has important behaviour - if any of Futures  has failed, `yield` will return immediately and will re-raise exception regardless of whether the other Futures are completed. To bypass it you can instead use [Mulit](http://tornadokevinlee.readthedocs.org/en/latest/gen.html#tornado.gen.Multi) or [multi_future](http://tornadokevinlee.readthedocs.org/en/latest/gen.html#tornado.gen.multi_future).

Note: I really don't know if RethinkDB requires separate connections, but I want to show concept.